# How do you get the checked value of asp:RadioButton with jQuery?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, radio-button, checked

I need to do something like this:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbDate" runat="server" Text="Date" GroupName="grpPrimary" />
```

and be able to check the value of the radio button's checked value in jQuery, but my attempts like these don't return true/false.

```
if ($('[name=rbDate]').attr("Checked"))

if ($('[name=rbDate]').attr("Checked").val())

if ($('[name=rbDate]:checked').val())
```

A little help?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is probably the easiest way to do it. The ***=** searches the whole id attribute for **rbDate** which takes care of the whole ASP.NET id mangling.

```
$('input[id*=rbDate]').is(":checked");
```

Comment: I don't get it. Why use the *contains* attribute filter when the ID is specific? Am I missing something?

Comment: +1 From me, by the way.  This answer is perfectly valid but if you don't have to it is fast to not have to match part of the id.

Comment: @karim79 - This is a rendered ASP.NET control which means that the rendered id will be mangled to include the id's of all the parent controls above this one.

Comment: @Andrew Hare - my goodness, I'm just not good with ASP.NET. So confused am I. Sorry for the spamming.

Comment: @karim79 - LOL, no worries :)

Comment: Thank you. This not only gave me what I wanted, but it was a good reminder about the name mangling.

Comment: That worked well and helped me.  Another option is: $('#<%=rbDate.ClientID%>').is(":checked");

Answer (score 5):

While [ChaosPandion's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541160/how-do-you-get-the-checked-value-of-aspradiobutton-with-jquery/1541177#1541177) will work it would be faster to wrap your `RadioButtonList` in a div like this:

```
<div id="dateWrapper">
    <asp:RadioButton 
        ID="rbDate" 
        runat="server" 
        Text="Date" 
        GroupName="grpPrimary" />
</div>
```

Then your jQuery code can be this simple:

```
var selected = $("#dateWrapper input:radio:checked");
```

Comment: This is a good solution but in the majority of cases you won't even notice the speed difference.

Comment: Extra divs for simpler (but not shorter) jQuery isn't a great tradeoff for what I'm doing. Thanks for the idea, though!

Answer (score 3):

INamingContainer adds a bunch of stuff to the beginning of the id of the actual html.

```
$('input[id$=rbDate]').attr('checked')
```

using the [id$=rbDate] bit on the selector tells jQuery that you want the input with an id that ends in rbDate

Now if you had a  that you wanted to get the selected value of the entire list you might do something like

```
$('input[name$=rbDate]:checked').val()
```

which, were one of the items selected would return the value of the selected , or , in that radio button list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my JQuery solution that uses the asp.net ID:

```
var rbSelected =  $("#<%= rbDate.ClientID %>").is(":checked");
```