# how to check radiobuttonlist is checked or not in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have tried using the following code for checking radiobutton selection but it shows alert even after selection

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() 
    {
    if (!document.getElementById('<%= Radiobuttonlist1.ClientID %>').checked) 
         {
                    alert("Please select type");
                    return false;
         }
    }
    </script>

        <asp:radiobuttonlist ID="Radiobuttonlist1" runat="server" 
                    RepeatDirection="Horizontal" >
                <asp:ListItem>Text</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Number</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Character</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:radiobuttonlist>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return validate();" onclick="Button1_Click"/>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541160/how-do-you-get-the-checked-value-of-aspradiobutton-with-jquery

Comment: When you call this function??

Comment: Can you check after extracting condition in some variable. Like :  var args =document.getElementById('<%= Radiobuttonlist1.ClientID %>').checked; if(!args){ alert("Please select type");
                return false;}

Comment: @Arpit, thats asp.net code. You can't get the element by using that Id as it will be populated dynamically by .Net

Comment: I am asking to check after making modifications in the function under <script> tag, which I understood is just the functional(javascript) code.

Comment: Problem here is the Id's are getting created at runtime. So its very difficult to get at the Id value.